# How to use $compile service more than once?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using Angular and I try to add directives to a page dynamically. I use the $compile service in a controller, like this:

```
var element1 = document.createElement('myDirective');
var element2 = document.createElement('myDirective');

$compile(element1)(scope);
$compile(element2)(scope); // error on this line

document.body.appendChild(element1);
document.body.appendChild(element2);
```

This works great for element1, but when I run **$compile(element2)(scope)** I get the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at http://localhost/Vendor/AngularJs/angular.min.js:6564:36
    at forEach (http://localhost/Vendor/AngularJs/angular.min.js:332:20)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost/Vendor/AngularJs/angular.min.js:6563:11)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost/Vendor/AngularJs/angular.min.js:6086:13)
    at publicLinkFn (http://localhost/Vendor/AngularJs/angular.min.js:5982:30)
    at MyController.addElements (http://localhost/Scripts/MyController.js:26:31)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, DOM manipulation in controllers is bad practice. You should look into using the ng-show, ng-if, ng-switch or ng-repeat directives for this.

If you're really sure that this is what you want, please move your DOM manipulation to a directive, and add your new elements to the element provided in the link function instead of document.body.

Then try using a cloneAttachFn in the link function call:

```
var myDirective = document.createElement('myDirective');
var linkFunction = $compile(myDirective);
linkFunction(scope, function (clone) {
  // element instead of document.body, we're in another directives link function
  element.append(clone); 
};
linkFunction(scope, function (clone) { 
  element.append(clone);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great. I actually do this in a directive in my real code. The reason I wrote controller above was to not include any more directives in the question then "MyDirective" :)